# How to protect an unsigned column against negative numbers?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a query like this:

```
UPDATE users SET reputation = reputation - 2 WHERE  id = :id
```

It throws an error sometimes when the current `reputation` is `0`. Since `reputation` column is `unsigned`. Is there any idea how can I solve the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `GREATEST()`:

```
UPDATE users SET reputation = GREATEST(reputation - 2, 1) WHERE  id = :id
```

And if `reputation` is `zerofill`, then `GREATEST(reputation - 2, 0)`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`CASE WHEN`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/case.html) to set the value if it is a positive value or a default value on negative value:

```
UPDATE users 
SET reputation = (CASE WHEN (reputation - 2 >= 0) THEN reputation - 2 ELSE 0 END) 
WHERE id = :id
```

You can set a default value on the `ELSE` part, if the value is lower than 0 (in this case `0`).

---

As @stack already mentioned in his answer you can use [`GREATEST`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html#function_greatest) (instead of `CASE WHEN`):

```
UPDATE users 
SET reputation = GREATEST(reputation - 2, 0)
WHERE id = :id
```

---

If you don't want to `UPDATE` in such a case you can check the value on `WHERE`:

```
UPDATE users 
SET reputation = reputation - 2 
WHERE id = :id
    AND (reputation - 2) >= 0
```